# Keypoints detection implementation

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I am working on keypoint detection, specifically identifying the left eye, right eye, and mouth of a cat.

For example, there is a 64x64 image of a cat.

[image]

And I created an image with circles on the left eye, right eye, and mouth of the cat.

[image]

I have created ImageDataGenerators for normal images:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False, 
    featurewise_std_normalization=False, 
    width_shift_range=0.1, 
    height_shift_range=0.1, 
    zoom_range=0.2)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=1,
    subset='training')

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=(64, 64),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=1,
    subset='validation')
```

Also for images with keypoints:

```
heatmap_train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=False, 
    featurewise_std_normalization=False, 
    width_shift_range=0.1, 
    height_shift_range=0.1, 
    zoom_range=0.2)

heatmap_train_generator = heatmap_train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    heatmap_train_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=1,
    subset='training')

heatmap_validation_generator = heatmap_train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    heatmap_val_path,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=32,
    seed=1,
    subset='validation')
```

Then zipped them together:

```
zipped_train_generator = zip(train_generator, heatmap_train_generator)
```

I have this model:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #    
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 64, 64, 3)]       0          
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 64)        1792       
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 64, 64, 64)        36928      
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 32, 32, 64)        0          
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 128)       73856     
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 128)       147584     
bottleneck_1 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 160)       5243040    
bottleneck_2 (Conv2D)        (None, 32, 32, 160)       25760      
upsample_1 (Conv2DTranspose) (None, 64, 64, 3)         1920       
Total params: 5,530,880  
Trainable params: 5,530,880  
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I am training the model:

```
history = model.fit((pair for pair in zipped_train_generator),
                    epochs=30,
                    validation_data = (validation_generator,heatmap_validation_generator)
                  )
```

It is working for more than 1 hour and it seems never ends:
[image]

Is this the right way to detect keypoints? If no, where I am doing wrong? How should I implement it?

Comment: Why are you zipping up the heatmap images and the cat images together?

Comment: Also I do not think drawing circles over the parts you want will help. I would suggest creating a dataset where you crop out the left eye, right eye and mouth and label them as so then train the model to identify those parts.

Comment: @yudhiesh This is from the task: To augment the inputs and targets the same way, you should create 2 separate generators, then you can zip them together.

Comment: As I understood I need to train model which should generate heatmap (image with dots) from normal image

Comment: But I do not know how to implement it

Comment: Heatmaps([Grad-CAMS heatmaps](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_ICCV_2017/papers/Selvaraju_Grad-CAM_Visual_Explanations_ICCV_2017_paper.pdf)) can be generated by showcasing the degree of activation of the model when viewing the image. This can be done at the final layer of a CNN. You need to use ```Adaptive Pooling``` before the final layers as well.

Comment: But this requires that the model is trained on labelling the eyes and mouth. So you have to train the model to first detect these then only can you draw heatmaps. This article explains it in [detail](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/heatmaps-and-convolutional-neural-networks-using-fast-ai-16d5b7d02a86).

Comment: @yudhiesh thank you for the article. I will take a look.